# how to stop my modal from opening on page load with out upsetting my update button and blocking datareader update

Tags: javascript

I have a modal form on my page on load it opens the form blank and it has an update button on a grid view that is the ID to pull data from SQL using the c# data reader to fill in the fields. and using the JS to show and hide elements depending if they are checked or selected.
all of this works but the modal form opens on page load.

```
        jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
   
    function openCoDetail() {

        $('#modCoDetail').on('show', function (e) {
            if (!data) return e.preventDefault() // stops modal from being shown
        });
        /*$('#modCoDetail').modal('show');*/
        console.log("ddlIssuetype value: " + $("#ddlIssuetype").val());

                $("#lblDriverArrivalDate").hide();
              //othershow and hide rules
                }         
        
    }
```

i have tried adding

```
 java
        jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
   
    function openCoDetail() {

        $('#modCoDetail').on('show', function (e) {
            if (!data) return e.preventDefault() // stops modal from being shown
        });
        /*$('#modCoDetail').modal('show');*/
        console.log("ddlIssuetype value: " + $("#ddlIssuetype").val());

                $("#lblDriverArrivalDate").hide();
              //othershow and hide rules
                }         
        
    }

       // Bind the function to the button click event
    $('#LinkButton1').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default behavior of the button
        e.stopPropagation(); // Stop the event propagation


        
        openCoDetail();
    });
    //// Bind the function to the button click event
    $('[id^="GvCompanies_lbUpdCompany"]').on('click', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default behavior of the button
        e.stopPropagation(); // Stop the event propagation

  
    openCoDetail();
  
    });
(jQuery);
```

but this caused the effect of the update not loading the data from the c#

and if I just comment out

```
/* openCoDetail();*/
```

in the original it will stop opening on page load but also won't open on any button click.
html

```
   grid view button 
   <asp:GridView ID="GvCompanies" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True"
                           DataKeyNames="ID"
                           CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" BorderColor="Silver"
                           OnRowDeleting="GvCompanies_RowCompleting"
                           OnRowCommand="GvCompanies_RowCommand"
                           EmptyDataText="No data for this request!">
   
   <ItemTemplate>
                                       <asp:LinkButton ID="lbUpdCompany" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'
                                           CommandName="UpdCompany" Text="Update" CausesValidation="false" CssClass="your-special-class"></asp:LinkButton>
                                   </ItemTemplate>
                                   
   modal
   <div class="modal fade" id="modCoDetail" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
               <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                   <div class="modal-content" style="font-size: 16px;">
```

c#

```
protected void GvCompanies_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "UpdCompany")
            {
                Comp_ID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                 GetCompany(Comp_ID);


                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openCoDetail();", true);
            }
        }
        
        private void GetCompany(int Comp_ID)
        {
            try
            {
                myCon.Open();
                using (SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.usp_GetDPDid", myCon))
                {
                    myCmd.Connection = myCon;
                    myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    myCmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Comp_ID;
                    SqlDataReader myDr = myCmd.ExecuteReader();

                    if (myDr.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (myDr.Read())
                        {

                            
                            ddlShopList.SelectedValue = myDr.GetValue(3).ToString();
                            ddlIssuetype.SelectedValue = myDr.GetValue(1).ToString();
                            //rest of the model fields
                                               }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { lblMessage.Text = "Error in Companies GetCompany: " + ex.Message; }
            finally { myCon.Close(); }
        }
```

if more info is required please let me know.
Cheers

Comment: Where is your HTML code? Try to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). So, just the HTML, CSS and JavaScript that illustrated the issue (you don't need to show us how you hide 20 elements in JS...).